# how to show hyperlinks in bot emulator

Tags: markdown, botframework

Microsoft bot framework used markdown.

If we need to add links, this is how we do in markdown:

```
[hello](www.greetings.com)
```

Now suppose the link itself contains round brackets, for example consider the scenario below:

```
[hello](www.gr(ee)tings.com)
```

markdown is showing the above link as:

hellotings.com)

because it takes the first closing bracket as the end of the link. How to handle such scenario?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to make this work using [reference-style links](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link), e.g.

```
[hello][some-id]

[some-id]: http://www.gr(ee)tings.com
```

Alternatively, escaping the inner parentheses should work:

```
[hello](www.gr\(ee\)tings.com)
```

Comment: Above solution works absolutely fine with online markdown editors. But not working with bot framework. I tried in Bot emulator and in Microsoft teams.

Comment: @Akshay, even the first suggestion of using reference-style links?

Comment: bot suggestions are not working for me. I tried using your suggestions in online markdown. It' working in online editor. But not on bot emulator.

Comment: Is it because I am using this method to replace ( with \( :   url = url.Replace("(",@"\(");

Comment: The solution i found was: Shorten the url, then convert it to hyperlink using markdown.